# Rspec: stubbed model method still being called in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In have this model in Rails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_auth_from_hash(hash)
    # stuff
  end
end
```

I want to stub the `create_from_auth_hash` method so I can isolate the controller behaviour. Apparently the current syntax for this is:

```
expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:create_from_auth_hash).and_return(false)
```

But even though I get no errors, the model method is still called.

How can I stub model methods? I'm using Rails 4.1 and RSpec 3.0.

Comment: Is `create_from_auth_hash` an instance method or a class method? Can you show how it's defined? (You can leave out the code in the method, just want to see the `def` part.)

Comment: @dpassage it's a class method, I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is set up to stub a method on any *instance* of `User`, not the class method you've defined on `User`.

To do that, you just pass `User` as the argument to `expect`, instead of an instance. Like this:

```
expect(User).to receive(:create_from_auth_hash).and_return(false)
```